# How can I align a question and a TikZ figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, horizontal-alignment, texstudio

```
\documentclass[10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\degre}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0,0.39,0}
\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49,0.49,1}
\begin{questions}
\question Find the value of $AC$ in the following diagram.
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-5,-1) rectangle (1,5);
\draw[color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0.59) -- (-0.59,0.59) -- (-0.59,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle; 
\draw (0,0)-- (0,4);
\draw (0,4)-- (-3.84,0);
\draw (0,0)-- (-3.84,0);
\draw [shift={(-3.84,0)}] plot[domain=0:0.81,variable=\t]({1*0.97*cos(\t r)+0*0.97*sin(\t r)},{0*0.97*cos(\t r)+1*0.97*sin(\t r)});
\draw (-2.82,1.02) node[anchor=north west] {$ \theta $};
\draw (-2.65,2.91) node[anchor=north west] {$ 85 m $};
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=xdxdff] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=xdxdff] (0.34,-0.21) node {$B$};
\fill [color=xdxdff] (0,4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=xdxdff] (0.22,4.36) node {$C$};
\fill [color=xdxdff] (-3.84,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=xdxdff] (-3.93,-0.29) node {$A$};
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (-0.7,0.85) node {$90\textrm{\degre}$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\thequestion}\end{figure}
\begin{choices}
\choice fkjj
\choice dji
\choice djfij
\choice jnfiejk
\end{choices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

In the above code i am getting this output.
[image]

But I am expecting that the diagram must come along the  question. That is rightside of the question and the choices must be left side. Or infact, the choices and diagram must occupy 4 line spaces only. Kindly help me to do this..

Comment: Do you want the diagram and the choices in a single line? Then don't use a floating figure and put both each in a minipage.

Comment: just remove `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`

Comment: what about minipage?@JuriRobl

Comment: you don't need a minipage, just use tikzpicture. `figure` is only require to tell latex that it can move the figure to help with page breaking.

Comment: I expect the question must be along the diagram(left side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there are things to do:

- remove the `figure` environment, since the picture should not float
- use the `baseline` option, so the sentence is not aligned to the bottom of the image, but to the top. You can even shift further, such as here:

  ```
  \question Find the value of $AC$ in the following diagram.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[...,
         baseline={([yshift={-0.75cm}]current bounding box.north)}]
  ...
  ```